# jquery set xml cdata

Tags: jquery, xml, cdata

I have a problem setting a cdata node with jquery. Getting cdata is easily done with the .text() function, but if I use .text('jquery > handy') it doesn't create a cdata node.

This is my procecure:
I get form data in xml to load in a form
something like this:

```
<formdata>
  <field id="title"><![CDATA[Some title]]></field>
  <field id="description"><![CDATA[Some description]]></field>
</formdata>
```

I use cdata nodes because a field can contain all kinds of special chars.
Then I load the data in the form by getting the node content with .text()

If the user posts the form, I update the xml and convert it to a sting to post it to the server. I know I could just post the fields, but I have some good reasons to put it in an xml document. Everything works very well, but not if the user does some input with special characters.
This is how i set the value of the node (in this example the "descriptioon node")

```
domdoc.find('field[id="description"]').text($("#description").val());
```

So the node used to be cdata, but the .text() function removes that. I alo tried this:

```
domdoc.find('field[id="description"]').text('<![CDATA[' + $("#description").val() + ']]>');
```

This also doesn't work because .text() changes < to &gt;

does anyone has a solution? My inspiration is gone.....

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set text, without adding `<![CDATA[`. CDATA is just one of the ways to escape text in XML, but since jQuery escapes for you, you don't need to use another method. `&lt;` is just as good as `<![CDATA[<]]>`. For XML applications they're identical.

Comment: Thanks porneL,
I'll try to figure it out that way.

Comment: Thanks to you I figured it out! still, its a bit strange you cannot use the cdata functionality....

Comment: This totally doesn't help you if you want, for example, some one to be able to insert HTML into your XML. Such as <html-comment><![CDATA[[Please click <a>here</a>.</html-comment>]]>

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution. Create a CData Section Node and Append it to your XML. I struggled with the JQuery .text() with no luck. This worked fantastic.

```
            var cDataSection = self.xmlDocument.createCDATASection(text);
            $(element).empty();
            $(element).append(cDataSection);
```