# jQuery XMLDocuments and strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dilemma that goes like this.

I have a string that represents XML. I want to manipulate that XML adding and updating nodes, and then I want the xml back as a string.

I have been working with javascript and jQuery and I have looked at several methods

WITH JQuery

```
var x_raw = "<?xml version='1.0'?><Q id ='23'><SQ id='201'><GP id='0'></GP></SQ></Q>"
var j_xml = $(x_raw)
.... Code for XML manipulation goes here ....
var x_string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(j_xml);
```

this produces a security exception in firebug

WITH Straight javascript

```
var x_raw = "<?xml version='1.0'?><Q id ='23'><SQ id='201'><GP id='0'></GP></SQ></Q>"
var xml = $.parseXML(x_raw);

newNode = xml.createElement("VALUE")
newText = xml.createTextNode("<![CDATA[Whooppeee]]>");

var insert = xml.getElementsByTagName('GP')[0].appendChild(newNode)
insert = insert.appendChild(newText)

var x_string = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xml);
```

This works but the CDATA code comes back as

`&lt;`![CDATA[Whoooppeee]] `&gt;`

I have tried the javascript escape trick

```
newText = xml.createTextNode("\<![CDATA[Whooppeee]]\>")
```

doesn't work either

WITH jQuery traversal function on an XML Document...

```
var x_raw = "<?xml version='1.0'?><Q id ='23'><SQ id='201'><GP id='0'></GP></SQ></Q>"
var xml = $.parseXML(x_raw);
var collection = xml.filter("SQ")
```

produces a firebug error "xml.filter is not a function"
Any jQuery DOM traversal function produces the same error.

I am ready to resort to string manipulation functions which would be ugly!
So any help or hints that get me some logical outcome would very much appreciated.

Regards
with much gratitude and appreciation of the collective wisdom of the overflow crew !

Gus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  [**createCDATASection()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createCDATASection)

```
newText = xml.createCDATASection("Whooppeee");
```

Comment: Why did I just know that somewhere out there there was going a simple answer to my question. I do try hard to find answers in the Googlesphere before posting here, maybe I am not finding the right references for the XML Dom

Many thanks to Dr Molle

Comment: w3c is always a good place to search for references :) http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#method-createCDATASection

Answer (score 0):

The last option that you are discussing is a good start:

```
var x_raw = "<?xml version='1.0'?><Q id ='23'><SQ id='201'><GP id='0'></GP></SQ></Q>"
var xml = $.parseXML(x_raw);
var collection = xml.filter("SQ")
```

After you parse your code with `$.parseXML(...)` the resulting object can't be yet traverse by jQuery. However if you add `$(xml)` you should find that all the standard jQuery functions will work. So just amend the above code to:

```
var x_raw = "<?xml version='1.0'?><Q id ='23'><SQ id='201'><GP id='0'></GP></SQ></Q>";
var xml = $.parseXML(x_raw);
var xmlDoc = $(xml);
var collection = xmlDoc.filter("SQ");
```

and you are in business.

To output the modified XML back to a string you can use `XMLSerializer` as follows:

```
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var xmlString = serializer.serializeToString(xml));
```

Note that in this case we pass the original parsed `xml` object, to the serializer rather then the jQuery-fied one.

Comment: Firstly thanks for taking the time to reply to this

I have tried your suggestion but I then return to the problem in the first scenario that is..the 'collection object' will not serialise back to a string with the XMLSerilazier.serializeToString(collection) function call and produces the firebug security error

Comment: I think I have figured out how you can output the modified XML document. I have a proof of concept fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/martineno/zdKPp/ that works in Firefox for me without any security warnings. Give that a try.

Comment: Ahhh I have missed that last bit about parsing the XML Document and not the jQuery object.. I will test this and let you know the outcome as I am under quite a bit of time pressure here.

Comment: I have progressed a little further in that my code actually does what I want it to at this stage. However there is always a problem..When I use the jQuery DOMmanipulation function node.append("<![CDATA[My non parseable stuff]]>") it returns, when serialized into a string it returns a comment <!--[CDATA[My non..]]-->. For every solution there appears to be a problem.  Any idea ?

Gus

Comment: @GusD After doing some searching it would appear that jQuery might have some issues with CDATA sections. This person: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246923/jquery-set-xml-cdata/7587119#7587119 just recommends using the `createCDATASection` function. Then you can append it using jQuery. Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but it will solve the problem. Just depends on how much you want to keep using jQuery to manipulate the XML document.

Comment: @martin_eno If there was a way of emailing you a case of beer I would !!